# load selected pre-existing files in blueimp

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am able to load all the files in a directory using blueimp file uploading plugin.

I just want to select only few of the files using filenames in that.
I know that get method of uploadhandler returns all the files in given directory but is there any way to select only few files?

This is what I have done to get all files..

```
public function getFile() {
        extract($this -> reqData);
        require_once ('path/to/UploadHandler.php');
        $options = array(
            'script_url' => "path to uploadhandler",
            'upload_dir' => "xxxxxxx",
            'upload_url' => "xxxxxxx",
            'type' => 'project_files'
        );

        $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
        exit;
    }
```

Please don't give negative remarks just because my editing is poor.
Thanks everybody...

Comment: I have the same challenge and was wondering if you accomplished this or would like to contribute to the post I created? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090215/how-to-download-manage-images-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload